# How do I add a suffix to the price field?

Tags: commerce

I'm using drupal commerce in my current project, I want to display the price like "$299 excluding tax/month", but the price field is not editable by default.
there is a way to add this suffix to the price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to include the value in the field? If not, you could just put it in place with a template file. You can create a template file that formats that specific field, for example; see [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656).

Otherwise, you can use the [Simple Field Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter) module.

> The Simple Field Formatter module allows site administrators to easily control the display of field values with following features.
>
> #### Features:
>
> - Prepend the field value with specified text/HTML
> - Append the field value with specified text/HTML
> - Reverse the Field Value
> - Trim the Field Value
> - Convert the field value to lowercase letters
> - Convert the field value to uppercase letters
> - Convert the first character of the field value to uppercase
> - Convert the first character of each word in the field value to uppercase (7.x-1.x-dev)
> - Replace some characters with some other characters in the field value (7.x-1.x-dev)
> - Link the field value to node(7.x-2.x-dev)

Comment: no I won't touch the field value, your idea is a smart way to do what I want.Just I thought there is a way to add suffix from user interface.thank you Guardian

Comment: kiamlaluno, I didn't understand what u mean by 'accepting it', the second solution of Guardian helped me even if his first solution is an alternative way.

Comment: Simple Field Formatter supports only Text fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Money](https://www.drupal.org/project/money), [Currency](https://www.drupal.org/project/currency) or [Measured Value Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/mvf) module.

The Money module will give you more advanced functionality including different type of currencies.